# Is it possible to restore a missing gvfsd-smb file?

Tags: package-management, files

Somehow I managed to delete my `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb` file on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not running Ubuntu Binary Beaver, but these commands should work for you:

```
# find out which package provides the file
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb
gvfs-backends: /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb

# force reinstallation see man apt-get
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-backends
```

Should restore the file.

Answer (score 1):

That file is part of the [`gvfs-backends` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gvfs-backends/filelist).

You should be able to restore it by simply reinstalling that package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gvfs-backends
```

Comment: Reinstalling did the trick. Thanks for the quick response.